# Magnetron as receiver

Tags: microwave, receiver, magnetron

If a magnetron is heated, but no high voltage applied, and microwave power of matching frequency is externally applied to its "output", would that produce a voltage across the HV terminals?

If so, how much power could be converted this way? Will this match the efficiency of the magnetron's normal operation?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "rectenna".

Answer (score 0):

The magnetron wouldn’t work. The magnetron is a vacuum tube diode.

It requires that the large “anode” be grounded and that the cathode is at a high negative potential (around -3000V) in order to become a "Current Rectifier"